# How to write camel blueprint (send email)

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint, apache-camel-mail

I'm trying sent mail with apache Camel with xml.
So I build postfix , dovecot and servicemix same server.
I wrote below xmlfile. but it doesn't work and occur a error

- precondition
- install Mail Component(camel)
- confirm bundle:list(status:active)

Please teach me how to write xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
  xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
    https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

  <!--  -->
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

  <!-- -->
  <route>
          <from uri="smtp://localhost?from=testuser01@domain?subject=testmail" />
          <to uri="pop3://localhost?to=testuser02@domain" />
  </route>

  </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

You can view the error below:

```
2018-08-06 00:46:44,007 | ERROR | mix-7.0.0/deploy | BlueprintCamelContext            | 40 - org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint - 2.16.4 | Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext(camel-3) due Protocol smtp cannot be used for a MailConsumer. Please use another protocol such as pop3 or imap.
```

============================================

@Namphibian 
Thank you for your quick reply. 
I fixed the code and retlied , but didn't work.

You can view the error below

・ERROR

```
WARN  |  pop3://IPAddress | MailConsumer                     | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | Consumer Consumer[pop3://IPAddress?to=user%40domain] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[pop3://IPAddress?to=user%40domain]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException - failed to connect, no user name specified?]
```

I thougut that I need to wirite username and Password, but didn't work

・CODE

```
<route>                                                                                                         
          <from uri="pop3://IPaddress?to=user@domain?username=user@domain?password=password" />
          <log message="received the message with this content: ${body}" />
          <to uri="smtp://IPaddress?from=admin@domain?subject=testmail" />
  </route>
```

You can view the error below

```
WARN  |  pop3://IPAddress | MailConsumer                     | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | Consumer Consumer[pop3://IPAddress?to=user%40domain%3Fusername%3Duser%40domain%3Fpassword%3Duser] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[pop3://IPAddress?to=user%40domain%3Fusername%3Duser%40domain%3Fpassword%3Duser]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException - failed to connect, no user name specified?]
```

How should I do to send and receive a mail?

============================================

Refixed code and tried again.
But didn't work.

・CODE

```
<route>                                                                                                         
          <from uri="pop3://IPaddress?to=user@domain?username=user@domain&amp;password=password" />
          <log message="received the message with this content: ${body}" />
          <to uri="smtp://IPaddress?from=admin@domain?subject=testmail" />
</route>
```

・ERROR

```
WARN  |  pop3://IPAddress | MailConsumer                     | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | Consumer Consumer[pop3://IPAddress?password=xxxxxx&to=user%40domain%3Fusername%3Duser%40domain] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[pop3://IPAddress?password=xxxxxx&to=user%40domain%3Fusername%3Duser%40domain]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException - [AUTH] Authentication failed.]
IPAddress
```

I thougut %40 represents @.
Should I fix some special charactor?

I find URL that wrote about how to escape special character.
But couldn't find bout "@".
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-uris-with-parameters-in-xml.html

Comment: Regarding your user authorization error check that you add the user id and passwords to the URL of the smtp and pop components.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP is used to send mail and POP is used to read mail. The reason you cannot use SMTP in the from part of the route is that you have nothing to send at a from.

Another point is that you are saying send a message to a POP component. POP is used to read mail. So your route is asking to do a read() a write component(SMTP).

```
<from uri="smtp://localhost?from=testuser01@domain?subject=testmail" />
```

You then ask to write() a read component(POP).

```
<to uri="pop3://localhost?to=testuser02@domain" />
```

If you reverse the order of the components so you read(from) a readcomponent(POP) and write(to) to the write component(SMTP) it would probably work.

In other words:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
<route>
      <from uri="pop3://localhost?to=testuser02@domain" /> 
      <log message="received the message with this content: ${body}"/>
      <to uri="smtp://localhost?from=testuser01@domain?subject=testmail" />
 </route>
 </camelContext>
```

Hope that makes sense. You had the components in the wrong order and they serve different purposes so the order would be important.